# Yahoo Finance scraping does not select collapsed rows

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I was trying to scrape all infos related to balance sheet, income statement and cash flow for, let say, KO, but my code does not detect the collapsed rows.
Can someone help me?

Site = https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/financials?p=KO

```
response = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/financials?p=KO')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
try:
  div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "D(tbr) C($primaryColor)")[0].find_all('span')
except:
  return self.stock + ' non è presente nel sito di YahooFinance'
columns = [span.text for span in div[1:]]
div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'D(tbrg)')[0]
values = dict()
for element in div:
  try:
    values[element.find_all('div', class_ = "D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px) undefined")[0].get('title')] = [i.text for i in element.find_all('div', {'data-test' : 'fin-col'})]
  except:
    pass
print(pd.DataFrame(values))
```

This code whill return  32 rows instead of  more than 45 rows, which are collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, it looks like the collapsed rows are not part of the static webpage. You might have to use a web driver such as [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to expand all of the rows.

I quickly did a search against all of the breakdown titles:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sorted([i.text for i in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'Va(m)'})]))
```

Here is what I saw:

```
['Basic Average Shares',
 'Basic EPS',
 'Cost of Revenue',
 'Diluted Average Shares',
 'Diluted EPS',
 'Diluted NI Available to Com Stockholders',
 'EBIT',
 'EBITDA',
 'Gross Profit',
 'Interest Expense',
 'Interest Income',
 'Net Income Common Stockholders',
 'Net Income from Continuing & Discontinued Operation',
 'Net Income from Continuing Operation Net Minority Interest',
 'Net Interest Income',
 'Net Non Operating Interest Income Expense',
 'Normalized EBITDA',
 'Normalized Income',
 'Operating Expense',
 'Operating Income',
 'Other Income Expense',
 'Pretax Income',
 'Reconciled Cost of Revenue',
 'Reconciled Depreciation',
 'Tax Effect of Unusual Items',
 'Tax Provision',
 'Tax Rate for Calcs',
 'Total Expenses',
 'Total Operating Income as Reported',
 'Total Revenue',
 'Total Unusual Items',
 'Total Unusual Items Excluding Goodwill']
```

Since "Operating Revenue" is not in the list, I figured it was generated dynamically. It uses a template to describe which breakdown titles a collapsed one has. The template name is `FinancialTemplateStore` within the static HTML.

Also, you might want to check out the following script to see how the collapsed rows are built using the template. It might help you figure out where the collapsed data comes from:

`https://s.yimg.com/uc/finance/dd-site/js/Quote.financials.7de24e8fee85155f7e70.modern.js`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I solved this problem by using click() from selenium library onto "Expand all".

Comment: @Pierluigi Great idea! Glad you could find a way to expand them.